# XPath and special characters

Tags: xpath, sitecore

I am having an issue with an XPath query I'm performing for a Sitecore CMS system.

This query works fine:

/root/content/Meta-Data/Tips/*

But when I try this:

/root/content/Meta-Data/Tips/*[@SomeAttribute='somekey']

I get an error which says "End of string expected at position 22" which is where the dash character is found.  I was under the impression that the dash was not a special character in XML... am I doing something wrong here?  Do I need to encode this in some way?  Or is this a bug in the XPath parser?  Any suggested workarounds?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change this:

```
/root/content/Meta-Data/Tips/*[@SomeAttribute='somekey']
```

To this:

```
/root/content/#Meta-Data#/Tips/*[@SomeAttribute='somekey']
```

Comment: That works.  Interestingly, it fails if I exclude the [@someattribute] filter.  You have a source for this?  I don't see it mentioned in the W3C Xpath doc.  It aslo fails on the XPath tester awshepard links below.

Comment: I see... it's not *really* a true XPath implementation.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar) for characters in tag names, the hyphen should be a valid character.  I've done a bit of XPath testing with [this site](http://www.xpathtester.com/) and found it helpful for comparing results with other parsers.

Comment: Thanks.  Both original queries work OK here with the dash node name.

Comment: Original website linked in this answer no longer works, updating to something that works.